# cannot debug icloud app: Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile

Tags: ios, code-signing, icloud, entitlements

I have followed all the steps in a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich to integrate iCloud:

- Created new cloud enabled app id
- Created, downloaded and installed provisioning profile with that app id into computer and device.
- Check the box for entitlement and iCloud in xcode project.
- Added "get-task-allow = YES"
   to entitlement
- Added code into xcode project to detect if icloud is enabled in AppDidFinishedLoading.

When I run it, I keep getting the error:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

Is it possible that it is not valid to debug an app with entitlement like in xcode 3? but then if I deleted it, then I can't access iCloud.....so how do I actually debug iCloud app??

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Incredibly weird!! I changed the code sign Debug field to other non-icloud enabled profile and I can run it.....! But of course it says "No iCloud access". So again, how do I debug iCloud app?

Comment: OK I solved it. I forget to turn on the iCloud for my new device...(which simply involve signing into my itunes account)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the culprit for all my code signing woos. I want to write it here so someone else can benefit from my experience.

First try all the steps I have put up previously. If it still doesn't work, do this :

```
Go to "PRODUCT" ---> "EDIT SCHEME" ---> Go to "Run app" and Change the setting to "DEBUG" (if it is in RELEASE for any strange reason).
```